# Back button (not browser) issue when redirect on the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

For back button, this is not the browser back button, but a back button on the page, I am using

```
<a href="@Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()">Back</a>
```

But If i have a delete functionality on the page which redirects to the same page, then I am not able to get the Request.UrlReferrer. It is always the same page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back();">Back</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-2);">Back</a>
```